# Javascript functions changing global variables

Tags: javascript, json

So I am making a scoring system where in the html there are input boxes on the left and right and it will add them up to decide which side is the winner. Once the winner is decided i want it to add one point to the global variable "score" of the team that wins. There will be another html page that shows which team is in the lead. These are my settings for global variables at the start.

```
var Team1 = {"Name":"Rockford Hills",
             "score": 0}
var Team2 = {"Name":"Pacific Bluffs",
             "score": 0}
var Team3 = {"Name":"Downtown",
             "score": 0}
var Team4 = {"Name":"Vinewood",
             "score": 0}
var Team5 = {"Name":"La Puerta",
             "score": 0}
var Team6 = {"Name":"Chumash",
             "score": 0}
var Team7 = {"Name":"Vespucci",
             "score": 0}
var Team8 = {"Name":"Los Santos",
             "score": 0}
```

This is the code that will add the point to the score object only problem is that when I go onto the other html page that links to the same java script sheet to look at the scores they are all on 0 as this function didn't overwrite the global variables.  I just need a bit of help on understanding how this all works and where i have gone wrong or if i can fix it as i am a bit of an amateur.

```
function submitR1M1(){
    var rightScores = document.getElementsByName('team2');
    var totalRight=0;
    for(var i=0;i<rightScores.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(rightScores[i].value))
            totalRight += parseInt(rightScores[i].value);
    }
    var leftScores = document.getElementsByName('team1');
    var totalLeft=0;
    for(var i=0;i<leftScores.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(leftScores[i].value))
            totalLeft += parseInt(leftScores[i].value);
    }

    if (totalLeft > totalRight)
        Team1.score = Team1.score + 1;
    else
        (Team2.score = Team2.score + 1);
    console.log(Team1.Name + Team1.score + Team2.Name + Team2.score);

}
```

Comment: You can't share a script between pages and have the pages share information via global variables. Save the shared information to `localStorage`, and read and parse it when you need it.

Comment: i think, while page load the 'score' is again initalized to value 0

Comment: // Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObj', value);

// Retrieve the object from local storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObj');